# Add to dashboard 'Global uptime' widget from a Synthetic test

Tags: datadog

Inside the view for a synthetic test there is an interesting visual metric that does not seem to be exportable:
[image]

The other widgets like `Response Time by Location` or `Network timings (averaged)` have a 'share' button. But not the one from the picture.
Is it possible to export or recreate it in a Dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an [SLO](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/service_level_objectives/) out of the synthetic test then use an [SLO widget](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/widgets/slo/) on your dashboard